# how select all element with the same class that aren't child of same class?

Tags: javascript, html

how to select only the parent element with a class?

- ❌ not all elements with a class like it do `document.querySelectorAll(".mycard")`
- ✅ but only the first parent element with the class,

  - and this element that we take don't need to have a parent with `.mycard`

it needs to return an array with all the divs that meet these conditions, and should work with every deep tree (10 of deep is a good point it is difficult to do)

- so it should not consider a div if not have the class, and go deep until finds the class we want, breaks, tries to search to others and repeat the process, and return us an array.
- if we find the wanted class, we add it to the array to return BUT

  - we need to check if the nested divs continue or not

    - if continue and we don't any other nested thing is fine don't return anything new
    - if it stops we need to search if there is another div with class, if add it to the array and repeat process until we finish the tree deep.

here is an example where you try your code:

```html
    <div class="mycard"> <!-- should get the parent only -->
      <div class="mycard">
        <div class="mycard">
          <div class="mycard"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mycard"> <!-- should get also this with a array of the fist and second -->
      <div class="mycard">
        <div class="mycard">
          <div class="mycard"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="another-div">
      <div class="mycard"> 
        <!-- should get also this that isn't in body directly -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="another-div">
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="mycard"> 
            <!-- should get also this that isn't in body directly -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="another-div">
      <div class="foo">
        <div class="bar">
          <div class="mycard"> <!-- this -->
            <div class="boo">
              <div class="mycard"> <!-- also this -->
              </div> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mycard"> <!-- this -->
      <div class="boo">
        <div class="mycard"> <!-- also this -->
          <div class="mycard"> 
            <div class="mycard"></div> 
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- returns [mycard, mycard, mycard, mycard, ...] 8 in total here, loopable in forEach -->
```

returns [mycard, mycard, mycard, mycard, ...] 8 in total here, loopable in forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName` and convert the result to an array. From there, you can use `.filter()`. Like this:

```js
let els = [...document.getElementsByClassName('mycard')];
els = els.filter(el => !el.parentNode.classList.contains('mycard'));

console.log(els);
```

```html
<div class="mycard">
  <!-- should get the parent only -->
  <div class="mycard">
    <div class="mycard">
      <div class="mycard"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mycard">
  <!-- should get also this with a array of the fist and second -->
  <div class="mycard">
    <div class="mycard">
      <div class="mycard"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="another-div">
  <div class="mycard">
    <!-- should get also this that isn't in body directly -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="another-div">
  <div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
      <div class="mycard">
        <!-- should get also this that isn't in body directly -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- returns [mycard, mycard, mycard, mycard] loopable in forEach -->
```

Comment: can you try also with the new requirements, the last 2 I added please, thanks I iwll upvote for now

Comment: @stackdeveloper I think that this solution also works with the last two requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily play with negation and descendant selectors to achieve
your requirement.

```js
//this will select all "mycard" classed elements 
//which are not descendants of any "mycard" classed elements.

document.querySelectorAll(".mycard:not(.mycard .mycard)");
```

You can also achieve it using JQuery.

```
$(".mycard").not('.mycard .mycard');
```